# Match exact string in column on bash

Tags: awk, grep, kubernetes

I have situation below, but I want only that column two is only `READY` and nothing else.

```
kubectl get nodes | grep "\<Ready\>"
10.5.0.11-c76ed   Ready,SchedulingDisabled   
10.7.0.13-d5bba   Ready 


kubectl get nodes | grep -w Ready
10.5.0.11-c76ed   Ready,SchedulingDisabled   
10.7.0.13-d5bba   Ready
```

I want this output:

```
10.7.0.13-d5bba   Ready
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `Ready` could be at the end of the line:

```
kubectl get nodes | grep 'Ready$'
```

or almost at the end of the line, save for some whitespace:

```
kubectl get nodes | grep 'Ready[[:space:]]*$'
```

or perhaps the only thing in field 2:

```
kubectl get nodes | awk '$2 == "Ready"'
```

Comment: first one did not work.. second worked. ` kubectl get nodes | awk '$2 == "Ready"'`

Comment: I wasn't sure if the trailing space was from actual data or a formatting "typo". I've added a variation to the Answer to account for trailing spaces.

Comment: only one works with the AWK.
kggn | awk '$2 == "Ready"' | sed -n -e 1,2p
10.44.0.13-b03d5bba   Ready                      node      1d        v1.10.9   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS   4.15.0-15-generic   docker://18.3.1
10.44.0.14-d30982c1   Ready                      node      1d        v1.10.9   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS   4.15.0-15-generic   docker://18.3.1

 kggn | grep 'Ready[[:space:]]*$' | sed -n -e 1,2p

 kggn | grep 'Ready$' | sed -n -e 1,2p